# Increase value + 1 within for loop in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I tried this:

```
posts = Posts.find({},
  sort:
    position: 1
).fetch()

for post in posts
  i = 1
  Posts.update post._id,
    $set:
      position: i
  i++
```

But all the posts end up with position 1. What I want is 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `i = 1` is within the loop... it's setting it to 1 for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force `i` to be evaluated (rather than referenced) at the right time by using `do`. From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

This is exactly the situation you're facing. You can also let CoffeeScript handle the loop counter by using the `for e, i in ...` form of `for`:

```
for post, i in posts
  do (post, i) ->
    Posts.update post._id,
      $set:
        position: i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
posts.forEach (post, i) ->
    Posts.update post._id,
        $set:
            position: i + 1
```